# Store several values in an array-like way and then access them

Tags: data-structures

I am building a kind of dictionary that consists of two parts: in the first one there are words, and in the second, roots. I would like to automatically keep track of which words are related to which roots. I already have the information to do so:

```
% \entryword[ROOT]{LANGUAGE}{WORD}{DESCRIPTION}
% \entryword[serve]{english}{reserve}{This is a wonderful word.}
% \entryword{english}{thing}{There's no root for this one.}
\newcommand{\entryword}[4][]{
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
        {}
        {
            % The optional argument, if not empty, represents the root.
            % Now, I would like to annotate this word in the list of
            % relatives of the specified root. It should be done here, I think.
        }
    \entryprompt{\foreignlanguage{#2}{#3}}
    #4

    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
        {}
        {
            Root: \textit{-#1-}.
        }
}
```

By having the relatives of each root conveniently stored in an array-like manner, I could then automatically print them:

```
% \entryroot{serve}{This root comes from latin.}
\newcommand{\entryroot}[2]{
    \entryprompt{\textit{-#1-}}
    #2

    % Here, how could I automate it?
    Relatives: .
}
```

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage[b5paper,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xifthen}


\newcommand{\entryprompt}[1]{
    {
        \par\noindent
        \textbf{\textsf{#1}}
    }
}

\newcommand{\entryword}[4][]{
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
        {}
        {
            % The optional argument, if not empty, represents the root.
            % Now, I would like to annotate this word in the list of
            % relatives of the specified root.
        }
    \entryprompt{\foreignlanguage{#2}{#3}}
    #4

    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
        {}
        {
            Root: \textit{-#1-}.
        }
}

\newcommand{\entryroot}[2]{
    \entryprompt{\textit{-#1-}}
    #2

    % Here, how could I automate it?
    Relatives: .
}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
    \Large
    \textbf{Words}
\end{center}

\newpage

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \entryword[serve]{english}{reserve}{This is a wonderful word.}
    \entryword{english}{thing}{There's no root for this word.}
\end{multicols}

\newpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
    \Large
    \textbf{Roots}
\end{center}

\newpage

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \entryroot{load}{I don't know where this one comes from.}
    \entryroot{serve}{This root comes from latin.}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Ideally, the relatives would be stored in a kind of table that could then be traversed, so that they could be printed in several ways. I've already looked at the `arrayjobx` package, and it doesn't seem to fill my requirements. In particular:

- Strings can't be indices.
- It doesn't seem to offer a simple way to add an element at the end of an array.

As egreg suggested, I'm adding a sample of the desired output:

> -- Words --
>
> reserve - This is a wonderful word.
>     Root: serve.
>
> thing - There's no root for this word.
>
> -- Roots --
>
> load - I don't know where this one comes from.
>
> serve - This root comes from latin.
>     Relatives: reserve.

Comment: An example of what output you're expecting would be useful.

Comment: The current example also works with LuaTeX

Comment: @percusse I meant, a solution implemented in Lua. I did not understand the solution provided by egreg; that was probably the reason I could not hack it as I wanted. Therefore, I tried to go for LuaTeX, but I don't get it yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define an array that's loaded with the relatives to a root, when `\entryword` is processed. When you use `\entryroot`, the array is printed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\entryprompt}{mm}{%
  \par\noindent\textbf{\textsf{#1}} #2%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\entryword}{ommm}
 {
  \entryprompt{\foreignlanguage{#2}{#3}}{#4}
  \IfValueT{#1}
   {% if a root is present, print it
    \ Root:\nobreakspace#1
    % then add the word as a relative to the root
    \kalrish_addtoroot:nn { #3 } { #1 }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\entryroot}{mm}
 {
  \par\noindent
  #1\nobreakspace--\nobreakspace#2
  % if the root has relatives, the corresponding sequence exists
  \seq_if_exist:cT { g_kalrish_root_ \tl_to_str:n { #1 } _seq }
   {
    % start printing the relatives
    \c_space_tl Relatives:~
    % separated by a comma
    \seq_use:cn { g_kalrish_root_ \tl_to_str:n { #1 } _seq } { ,~ }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \kalrish_addtoroot:nn #1 #2
 {
  % if a root appears for the first time, allocate a sequence
  \seq_if_exist:cF { g_kalrish_root_ \tl_to_str:n { #2 } _seq }
   {
    \seq_new:c { g_kalrish_root_ \tl_to_str:n { #2 } _seq }
   }
  % add the current word as a relative
  \seq_gput_right:cn { g_kalrish_root_ \tl_to_str:n { #2 } _seq } { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Words}

\entryword[serve]{english}{reserve}{This is a wonderful word.}

\entryword{english}{thing}{There's no root for this word.}

\entryword[serve]{english}{service}{This is also a word of tennis}

\section{Roots}

\entryroot{load}{I don't know where this one comes from.}

\entryroot{serve}{This root comes from latin.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works like a charm. Fantastic!

Comment: I have been trying it, but couldn't get it: how would one make each of the relatives appear as, say, italic? Where would one insert the _textit{…}_?

Comment: @Kalrish Say `\textit{\seq_use:cn ...}` in the line after the “Separated by commas” comment

Comment: That way, either the comma itself is italicized (which I don't like) or bad output is produced. As a more compelling task, what if one wanted to make a cross-reference to the place where the word is defined? (One would need the word itself)

Comment: @Kalrish I can't guess what you have in mind. A new question with a *complete* set of specifications will surely help better.

Comment: I'm not sure it deserves a new question. The original one already asked about accessing each word stored in the "array", so that it could be individually manipulated. Italicizing it, or using it as an argument to a `\ref{…}`, are both use cases of the original question… aren't them?

Answer (score 3):

Another solution without the need of any package (because only TeX primitives and basic macros are used):

```
\def\sxdef#1{\expandafter\xdef\csname#1\endcsname}
\def\entryword{\def\opt{}\futurelet\next\entrywordA}
\def\entrywordA{\ifx\next[\expandafter\entrywordB \else \expandafter\entrywordC \fi}
\def\entrywordB[#1]{\def\opt{#1}\entrywordC}
\def\entrywordC#1#2#3{{\bf#2} #3%
   \ifx\opt\empty \else \space Root: \opt
      \expandafter\ifx \csname r:\opt\endcsname \relax \sxdef{r:\opt}{#2}%
      \else \sxdef{r:\opt}{\csname r:\opt\endcsname, #2}\fi
   \fi}
\def\entryroot#1#2{#1 -- #2%
   \expandafter \ifx \csname r:#1\endcsname \relax \else
      \space Relatives: \csname r:#1\endcsname \fi
}

\entryword[serve]{english}{reserve}{This is a wonderful word.}

\entryword{english}{thing}{There's no root for this word.}

\entryword[serve]{english}{service}{This is also a word of tennis}

\entryroot{load}{I don't know where this one comes from.}

\entryroot{serve}{This root comes from latin.}

\end
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a demonstration suitable for further editing, the skeleton is programmed in LuaLaTeX.

We store all the words and roots in two external files and load them on next TeX runs. The key line is `\newcommand\entryword[4][]{\directlua{storeword([[#1]],[[#2]],[[#3]],[[#4]])}}` which passes all TeX arguments to Lua, into the `storeword` function in this example. We could even process TeX file (plain text) by Lua without TeXing.

There are many possible improvements, we could add:

- Page numbers: definitions<->lists in both directions (`\label`, `\ref`, `\pageref`).
- Cross references: words<->roots in both directions (with or without testing of the presence of the entries).
- Sort the entries (e.g. in Lua, MakeIndex, Xindy, Biber, ...). Now, the entries are hashed, so after each run of TeX we may get different order of entries. Try it for yourself. :-)

We run `lualatex`, I enclose the `mal-root.tex` file and a preview of the result.

```
% lualatex mal-root.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{luacode}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
malwords={}
malroots={}

-- Store a single word to a data table...
function storeword(root,lang,word,text)
-- print(root,lang,word,text)
-- split root(s) to a table
  roots={}
  for singleroot in string.gmatch(root, "([^,]+)") do
    table.insert(roots, singleroot)
  end
  malwords[word]={ roots, lang, text }
end -- function storeme

-- Store a single root to a data table...
function storeroot(root,text)
-- print(root,text)
  malroots[root]={ text }
end -- function storeroot

-- Print both lists (words, roots)...
function printall(orderfile)
-- load stored files if they exist
  for _,malf in pairs({"dumpwords.lua","dumproots.lua"}) do
    f=io.open(malf,"r")
    if f then f:close(); dofile(malf); end -- print(malf); 
  end -- for, files

-- Typeset the first list...
  if orderfile==1 and malwordsfull then  -- words
    tex.print("\\section{List of Words}")
    for theword,term in pairs(malwordsfull) do 
      mals="\\textbf{"..theword.."}  -- "..term[3]
      if #term[1]>0 then 
        mals=mals.." Root"
        if #term[1]>1 then mals=mals.."s" end
        mals=mals..": "
        for elemi,elem in pairs(term[1]) do
          mals=mals..elem
          if elemi<#term[1] then mals=mals..", " end
        end -- for
      end -- if #>0
      mals=mals.."\\par"
      tex.print(mals)
    end
  end -- words

-- Typeset the other list (to add cross references?)

  if  orderfile==2 and malrootsfull then -- roots
    tex.print("\\section{List of Roots}")

-- Check all roots...
    for theword,term in pairs(malrootsfull) do 
      mals="\\textbf{"..theword.."} -- "..term[1]
      toadd=""; counter=0
-- Check all words...
      for elem,oword in pairs(malwordsfull) do
-- Check all roots in words...
        for oroota,oroot in pairs(oword[1]) do
          if oroot==theword then counter=counter+1; toadd=toadd..elem..", " end
        end -- for rootsfull
      end -- if orderfile
      if counter>0 then
        mals=mals.." Relative"
        if counter>1 then mals=mals.."s" end
        mals=mals..": \\textit{"..string.sub(toadd,1,-3).."}"
      end -- if
      mals=mals.."\\par"
      tex.print(mals)
    end -- for

  end -- if
end -- function printwords()

-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168058/lua-beginner-table-dump-to-console
function dumper(o)
  if type(o) == 'table' then
    local s = '\n{'
    for k,v in pairs(o) do
      if type(k) ~= 'number' then k = '"'..k..'"' end
      s = s .. '['..k..'] = ' .. dumper(v) .. ', '
    end
    return s..'}\n'
  else
    return '"'..tostring(o)..'"'
  end
end

-- Save data to a single file...
function savedata(file, data, name)
  saveme=io.open(file, "w")
  mojkovo=name.." = "..dumper(data, name)
  saveme:write(mojkovo)
  saveme:close()
end

-- Save both data tables...
function saveall()
  savedata("dumpwords.lua", malwords, "malwordsfull")
  savedata("dumproots.lua", malroots, "malrootsfull")
end
\end{luacode*}


% Let's call Lua...
\newcommand\entryword[4][]{\directlua{storeword([[#1]],[[#2]],[[#3]],[[#4]])}}
\newcommand\entryroot[2]{\directlua{storeroot([[#1]],[[#2]])}}
\newcommand\printwords{\directlua{printall(1)}}
\newcommand\printroots{\directlua{printall(2)}}
\newcommand\savedata{\directlua{saveall()}}

% Call Lua to work (data from the previous TeX run)...
\printwords
\printroots

% Let's test if it works (some words) and ...
\entryword[sleep1,sleep2]{english}{sleeping}{A word with more roots.}
\entryword[serve]{english}{reserve}{This is a wonderful word.}
\entryword{english}{thing}{There's no root for this word.}
\entryword[serve]{english}{service}{This is also a word of tennis.}

% ... and (some roots)
\entryroot{load}{I don't know where this one comes from.}
\entryroot{serve}{This root comes from latin.}

% Save all data to two external files for next TeX run...
\savedata
\end{document}
```

[image: an example: two lists generated]

Comment: I'm keeping egreg's answer as my accepted answer because he first answered what I asked. Nevertheless, this is a fantastic answer. It seems I am still hitting a bug with some packages, unfortunately.

Comment: @Kalrish If you get stuck, please feel free to modify the original question or post a new one. We are all bug hunters and hungry enough to get them... :-)